# JavaScript For Drill

Tags: javascript, for-loop

my code isn't running, I need to get two numbers and print all the numbers between them.
that is the code:

```html
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var minNum = window.prompt("Enter min number:");
        var maxNum = window.prompt("Enter max number:");
        if (maxNum - minNum != 1 && maxNum > minNum)
        {
            for (i = (minNum + 1); i < maxNum; i++)
            {
                document.write(i + "<br />");
            }
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You need to convert the numbers from strings to integers. Use `parseInt()`

Comment: parseInt(minNum)?

Comment: `var minNum = parseInt(prompt("Enter min number"))`

Comment: You haven't defined variable "i", do like ```for (var i = (minNum + 1); i < maxNum; i++)``` in your code and also use parseInt()

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use window.prompt you need to parse the result.

**window.prompt** returns a String by default so once you get the values you must convert that into a Number in order to make your code work

Here is an example:

```js
var minNum = window.prompt("Enter min number:");
var maxNum = window.prompt("Enter max number:");
if (maxNum - minNum != 1 && maxNum > minNum) {
minNum = minNum * 1
maxNum = maxNum * 1
  var wrapperElement = document.querySelector('body')
  for (i = (minNum + 1); i < maxNum; i++) {
    wrapperElement.innerHTML += (`${i}<br />`);
  }
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: *you must convert that into an integer* <-- JavaScript doesn't have integers. It only has floats.

Comment: well call it number then which JavaScript does have, I think the concept is understood

Comment: With new coders, it's very important that we use the right terminology so they don't get the wrong idea. To be clear, JavaScript only has one numeric type, `Number` (as you say) and that type stores floating point numbers.

Comment: Agree about new coders comment, thanks, I've made the change ;)

Answer (score 0):

**You have two issues:**

First, you are using [`document.write()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/write) which should not be used as it will cause any previously loaded document to be thrown out and a new one created every time you use it. `document.write()` is a very old API that has very limited uses in modern JavaScript code. Instead, you should write the value to a pre-existing element that is already on the page.

Second, all data in HTML is strings. To use them as numbers in JavaScript, you have to convert them (either implicitly or explicitly). There are several ways to do this, but one way is to prepend the string with `+`.

```html
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
  <!-- The output from the script will be placed
       within this element. -->
  <div></div>
  
  <!-- The default type for a script is JavaScript, so you don't 
       need to write that. -->
  <script>
    // Get a reference to the div
    const output = document.querySelector("div");
    
    // window is the global object in a browser and
    // so you can omit explicitly stating it
    var minNum = +prompt("Enter min number:");
    var maxNum = +prompt("Enter max number:");
    
    if (maxNum - minNum != 1 && maxNum > minNum) {
      for (i = (minNum + 1); i < maxNum; i++){
         // To be able to have the HTML portion parsed
         // as HTML, use .innerHTML on the output element.
         // Also, to make the new value be appended to 
         // the current value, we use += instead of =.
         output.innerHTML += i + "<br>";
      }
    }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```